Denied entrance into the UK 30 yrs ago, will I need a visa to visit friends in London?
30 yrs ago as a Canadian backpacker I met my boyfriend at the time in Asia. We traveled through India & Nepal returning to England, where he is from originally. I was denied entry into the UK due to inadequate funds. The interview officer felt I had been traveling an extended period. They believed I would likely work while there, which was likely true.
I was given permission to visit for the weekend. The interview officer  kept my passport as security for my return. I decided to stay longer since they already had my passport. Once I left the country (several months later) they returned my passport to me. On my way back to Canada there was no mention of a life ban or any sort of  restriction. All these years later I would like to return as a visitor. I'm a retired nurse. I've been married 25 yrs. Have a good pension. Do I need to apply for a visitor's visa after all this time?

First time I've heard of a passport being confiscated at an immigration entry point like that. It's weird because with no visa and no passport, how would you even identify yourself and defend your legal entry if somebody questions it? Not like other foreign IDs are valid besides the passport. You'd be kind of like an undocumented alien in the country. How would one even identify themself as the true owner of the passport when exiting?

Just out of interest, after narrowly avoiding being denied entry, what made staying for months longer than your entry permission seem like a good idea?

@JoL There's no requirement to carry ID inside the UK anyway

Traveller21- while I agree staying beyond the allowed time was not the brightest thing I've ever done. The flip side I was young , had a partner and made a bad choice. I own that. It's called being human. No such thing as cell phones back then. Couldn't just text your folks for immediate advice. Sometimes you learn the hard way.

@Mimiflower Like I said, provided you enter at an airport equipped with eGates (such as Heathrow, Gatwick or Manchester), and correctly insert your passport and fingerprints into the gate, you may well bypass a human check altogether

I'm confused, were you denied entry into the UK, or were you given permission to visit for the weekend?

@NickBarnes She was refused leave to enter but granted temporary admission

@Crazydre: Not sure how you can be granted admission and denied entry at the same time, but I hope I never find out

@NickBarnes Yeah, it's a weird UK thing

@NickBarnes, yes it's a thing. You kinda fall into nomads land. Your not view as a huge concern ( can commonwealth ) but insufficient funds. They want you to go home. So they give you special permission with a forn. File number on it. They keep the passport let you leave to make arrangements etc. It was actually very good of them. It's totally on me. There was a lot of moving parts. Relationships when you're traveling. Not so unsusal.

No, you don't specifically need a visitor's visa, and as you weren't notified of any ban, you're not prohibited from entry.
However, I'd bring ALL evidence of your ties to Canada (house/apartment contract, all the past year's pension payment confirmations, return ticket etc.) and place it in a soft binder, so you can present this evidence if asked.
Depending on the airport, you may not need to speak to a human at all, as Canadian passports are eligible for eGates where available.
If there are no eGates at the airport of arrival, or it flags your passport, you'll be referred to an officer. If so, be prepared for the possibility of being sent to secondary screening for hours, but as long as you prepare yourself with substantial proof of your ties to Canada, you should eventually be fine.

Most likely any information about how happened back then is long lost.

Also, while you should have the information mentioned here available, you should only provide it if they ask. Don’t drown them with information they didn’t ask for.

Thxs so much. It seems ridiculous as I was a young free spirit back then. Now I'm just older & wiser. Thxs again

Flying via Ireland could also be helpful. Less of a chance to be flagged and no immigration checks on flights from Ireland.

@JonathanReez Random checks do take place https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2024/sep/22/arrests-made-in-uk-crackdown-against-gangs-exploiting-irish-border

@Mimiflower The UK isn't too keen on forgetting or even forgiving, so tread with caution as I described.

@Traveller Only by air/sea though, not at the land border. In-country checks also exist at Belfast airports and the ferry ports of Cairnryan and Liverpool - I've encountered two such checks which were both by Merseyside police arriving on the overnight Stena ferry Belfast-Liverpool

@Traveller if you fly direct you’re guaranteed to be checked and questioned in depth, assuming the UK still has data on OP. If you fly via Ireland you reduce your odds of any extra checks being done.

@JonathanReez If you fly direct you can use eGates if available, so may well sail through

@JonathanReez But if you do get checked, if the person doing the checking gets the impression that you're structuring your travel through Ireland to evade border controls, there's a good chance they're going to deny you entry and slap you with a ban, even if they might have otherwise let you in if you entered directly. (Which is to say, if you fly into Ireland, have a legitimate reason that Ireland is your first port of call.)

@R.M. that's a bit of a stretch. A perfectly legitimate reason is trying to save on airfare: flying via Ireland vs direct can often save money, no further reason is required.

@R.M. Merely assuming you entered through Ireland to avoid being checked is NOT grounds for a ban.

@JonathanReez One thing I did remember now, though, is that if one was refused leave to enter on the last entry, entering at the Irish land border is automatically an illegal entry, and if entering by air/sea you have to approach Border Force even if they aren't doing a random check. I'm not sure tbh how getting temporary admission and violating the terms counts for this purpose

@JonathanReez Yes, price is a legitimate reason. However, if you do get stopped and asked why you flew into Ireland instead of direct, and you reply "because it was cheaper" ... but you didn't check if it was cheaper or you did and it wasn't, well, then you just lied to the border agent. Which is not something you want to be participating in.

@R.M. Unless you're disqualified from deemed leave, Border Force cannot refuse you entry arriving from Ireland. They're primarily there to establish if you're covered by deemed leave, and if so to wave you on. If you're disqualified (which again I'm not sure whether OP is), only then they can choose to grant or refuse leave to enter. In other words, unless you're disqualified from deemed leave, you can literally brag to them about seeking to illegally immigrate for life and sponge off the UK welfare system; they still must let you in!
